# How to create tuples out of the list of angle brackets followed by unbracketed words

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to create a list of tuples where the first item of the tuple is the bracketed part and the second item is the word. How to forward with my current code?

Here is part of my output.

`['<s n="1">', '<w NN1>Literacy ', '<w PRP>in ', '<w NN1>Theory\n', '</head>\n', '<pb n=18> ', '<pb n=19>\n', '</div1>\n', '<div1 type="u" n=1>\n', '<head>\n', '<s n="2">', '<w AT0>THE ', '<c PUQ>&bquo;', '<w AJ0>AUTONOMOUS', '<c PUQ>&equo; ', '<w NN1>MODEL', '<c PUN>: ', '<w CRD>I ', '<w NN1>LITERACY ', '<w CJC>AND ', '<w NN1>RATIONALITY\n', '</head>\n', '<p>\n', '<s n="3">', '<w PNP>I ', '<w VM0>shall ', '<w VVI>attempt ', '<w TO0>to ', '<w VVI>establish ', '<w AT0>the ', '<w AJ0-NN1>general ', '<w NN2>outlines ', '<w PRF>of ', '<w DTQ>what ', '<w PNP>I ', '<w VVB>term ', '<w AT0>the ', '<c PUQ>&bquo;', '<w AJ0>autonomous', '<c PUQ>&equo; ', '<w NN1>model ', '<w PRF>of ', '<w NN1>literacy ', '<w PRP>by ', '<w VVG>examining ', '<w PRP-AVP>in ', '<w NN1-VVB>detail ', '<w AT0>the ', '<w NN1>work ', '<w PRF>of ', '<w DT0>some ', '<w NN2>writers ', '<w PNQ>who ', '<w VHB>have ', '<w AV0>explicitly ', '<w VVN>addressed ', '<w PNX>themselves`

```
for item in l_needed:
    if ">" in item:
            cutindex=item.index(">")
            partone=item[:cutindex+1]
            parttwo=item[cutindex+1:]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Please provide some complete example input and your expected output. You can [edit] the question. See [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple_0 = []    
for item in l_needed:
    if ">" in item:
            cutindex=item.index(">")
            partone=item[:cutindex+1]
            parttwo=item[cutindex+1:]
            tuple_0.append((partone, parttwo))
```

Try this code, and it creates a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any example of expected output (for example, there are many whitespaces; what do you want to do with them?) and so, I can only guess.

If you want to have the brackets included with the first parts but not include any whitespaces, you just need to start with an empty list of tuples, and append a new item (tuple) each time a valid entry is found in the loop:

```
tuples = []
for item in l_needed:
    if ">" in item:
        cutindex=item.index(">")
        partone=item[:cutindex+1].strip()
        parttwo=item[cutindex+1:].strip()
        tuples.append((partone, parttwo))
print(tuples)
```

If you'd also like to strip the brackets, you can use this code:

```
tuples = []
for item in l_needed:
    # make sure there are no whitespaces before "<" (and at the end of part two):
    item = item.strip()  
    if ">" in item:
        cutindex=item.index(">")
        # in part one, remove possible whitespaces (inside) next to the brackets:
        partone=item[1:cutindex].strip()
        # in part two, remove possible whitespaces between brackets and part two:
        parttwo=item[cutindex+1:].strip()  
        tuples.append((partone, parttwo))
```

Alternatively, you could use `split`; this is an example without stripping whitespaces and keeping the brackets:

```
tuples = []
for item in l_needed:
    aux = item.split('>', 1)
    if len(aux) > 1:
        partone = aux[0] + '>'
        parttwo = aux[1]
        tuples.append((partone, parttwo))
```